# How to delete repeated IDs and sum values of them in excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have ID & Value columns but each ID can repeat again in ID column.
I want to each ID shows once with sum of values of it and delete repeated rows.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Insert Tab -> Pivot table. Then drag 'ID' into the Rows block, and 'Value' into Values. By default this will summarise the values for each ID (though it's capable of doing a lot more!)

Answer (score 1):

Sort data by ID column, use subtotals to sum the value in every change on ID. Copy the data showing subtotals in another sheet if further manipulation is required.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Josh Friedlander in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952015/3846228), you should use a Pivot Table to achieve this.
Here's an example of how you can create and configure your PT:

1st:

[image]

2nd:

[image]

3rd:

[image]

4th:

[image]

5th:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your columns and sort them by ID :

   **HOME** tab > **Editing** box > **Sort & Filter** > **Sort Smallest to Largest**

   (start selecting with ID column)

---

2. Create **Frequency** column and for **first** cell of it enter this code in **Function** :

   `=FREQUENCY(A2:A7,A2:A7)`

   then **drag** cell to the latest row to extend function.

   (**A2:A7** = cell range of IDs)

---

3. Create **SumOfValues** column and for **first** cell of it enter this code in **Function** :

   `=SUM(B2:INDEX(B:B,(ROW(B2)+VALUE(C2)-1)))`

   for **second** cell of **SumOfValues** enter this code in **Function** :

   `=IF(LOOKUP(VALUE(A3),$A$2:A2)<VALUE(A3),SUM(B3:INDEX(B:B,(ROW(B3)+VALUE(C3)-1))),"DeleteMe")`

   then **drag** **second** cell to the latest row to extend function.

   (**A** = ID column, **B** = Value column, **C** = Frequency column

   **A2** = first ID cell, **B2** = first Value cell, **C2** = first Frequency cell

   **A3** = second ID cell, **B3** = second Value cell, **C3** = second Frequency cell)

---

4. Select **Frequency** & **SumOfValues** columns and press **Ctrl+C** then :

   **Right-Click** on next empty column > **Paste Special** > **Paste Values** > **Values**

---

5. Select **SumOfValues** column then :

   - **HOME** tab > **Editing** box > **Find & Select** > **Find**
   - enter `DeleteMe` in **Find what** box, select **`By Rows`** in **Search** & **`Values`** in **Look in**
   - then press **Find All** and press **Ctrl+A** then press **Close**
   - **HOME** tab > **Cells** box > **Delete** > **Delete Sheet Rows**
   - Select **Frequency** & **SumOfValues** columns then **Right-Click** > **Delete**